# How to use value from input field in api request?

Tags: angular

I got input field where you have to type a city name to receive a weather data for that city.
I use Angular 9, at the moment I can just display the data in html with defined London name.

// UPDATED weather components

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {WeatherService} from '../_service/weather.service';
import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather',
  templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather.component.scss']
})
export class WeatherComponent implements OnInit {
  weatherUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  apiKey = '0887a6ce526907cc80121d591e5adbdd';
  weatherIconUrl = 'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/';
  cityName = 'London';
  data = [];
  temp: number;
  description: string;
  icon: string;
  error = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
          private weatherService: WeatherService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.fetchData();
    this.getCityData();
  }

  getCityData() {
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    queryParams = queryParams.append('q', this.cityName);
    queryParams = queryParams.append('appid', this.apiKey);
    this.http.get(this.weatherUrl, {params: queryParams})
      .pipe(debounceTime(1000))
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data.push(data);
        this.temp = Math.round(this.data[0].main.temp);
        this.description = this.data[0].weather[0]?.description;
        this.icon = this.weatherIconUrl +         
        this.data[0].weather[0]?.icon + '.png';
      });
  }
```

html

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="getCityData()" [(ngModel)]="cityName">
<div *ngIf="!error">
  <p>City: {{cityName}}</p>
  <p>Temp: {{temp}}</p>
  <p>Descr: {{description}}</p>
  <img [src]="icon" height="70px" alt="no image">
  <p *ngIf="error">{{error.message}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's 100% not how angular works. Look into ReactiveFormsModule. Here's a quick stackblitz https://angular-ivy-jqbypd.stackblitz.io

Comment: @baao it doesn't open the link

Comment: I believe there is no need to check the ReactiveFormsModule. This should be used in when creating forms. If you are new to angular and which to use a form I would suggest you go with Template driven forms (FormsModule) but again I believe there is no need. For your specific case you need to know some angular concepts:
*putting a reference name to your input , i.e: #myInput, and then use its value to pass it to the get function (your text variable)
*observables: to subscribe to this async request (you connecting to the api endpoint)

Comment: ***CONTINUATION***
*pipes:  (as the map() you have in your code also used in js) to transform the response data.
If you can provide the url of the api and the apikey(at least the url), I can provide an example code otherwise please read about this concepts. @KristiyanPetrov

Comment: @Armando i'll really appreciate it if you can provide some example, that's my api url - https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&units=metric&APPID=eb03b1f5e5afb5f4a4edb40c1ef2f534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are several approaches to get what you want to achieve but for a basic example we can do it as the code below. Before going to the code I believe you should know it would be better if your api requests are inside a **service** and then you call the **service** from your **components**. By doing it this way, you can simplify your code and reuse it across all your project. If you do not know about services please go an check at a tutorial in the angular oficial docs https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4 or serach in google about it.
Note: donot forget to add **WeatherComponent** in **app.modulte.ts declarations** and **HttpClientModule** in the **app.module.ts imports**.

Now the code:

App.component.html

```
<app-weather></app-weather>
```

weather.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather',
  templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather.component.css']
})
export class WeatherComponent implements OnInit {
  // setting the httpClient  in the constructor
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  // The base url where you want to get the data, we will then add the app id and the city name
  baseUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  appID = 'eb03b1f5e5afb5f4a4edb40c1ef2f534';
  // Defining the city name variable, since we are doing  two way binding in the template then London will appear at first
  cityName = 'London';
  // Here we will store the response we get from the api
  responseData = null;
  // Now when we first enter the component we want to get a response from the api with our default value, in this
  // case: London
  // Your variables
  data: any;
  temp: number;
  description: string;
  icon: string;
  // You did not provide this but I believe this is the one
  weatherIconUrl = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/';
  // Error variable
  error = null;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCityData();
  }

  getCityData() {
    // You can add query parameters in many ways. For example, you can add them directly to the string
    // (https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&units=metric&APPID=eb03b1f5e5afb5f4a4edb40c1ef2f534) or
    // concatenating several strings. ie: baserUrl + '?q=' + cityName + '&APPID='+ appId
    // But we will do it adding a params Object to the request, its ( I believe) a better approach when dealing with
    // very long urls where you can make mistakes really fast so:
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    // We have to append this way because HttParams objects are immutable ( can't be modified so we need a new one)
    queryParams = queryParams.append('q', this.cityName);
    queryParams = queryParams.append('APPID', this.appID);
    // Since we are using two way data binding our city name change whenever the input change so it will always be
    // up to date.
    // Now we make the request with our custom parameters
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl, {params: queryParams})
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      // then we subscribe
      .subscribe(responseData => {
      // This is part of your code but I change some things. Of course you can map to construct a object with your
      // response but to keep it simple:
      this.data = responseData;
      this.temp = Math.round(this.data.main.temp);
      this.description = this.data.weather[0].description;
      this.icon = this.weatherIconUrl + this.data.weather[0].icon + '.png';
      this.error = null;
      }, error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
  }

}
```

weather.component.html

```
<!--If you do not want to use two way data binding you can pass the input element in the function or the event...-->
<!--Also you can put the input in the app component and then pass the value to the weather component but I put it here -->
<!--for explanation purpose-->
<input type="text" (keyup)="getCityData()" [(ngModel)]="cityName">
<div *ngIf="!error">
  <p>City: {{cityName}}</p>
  <p>Temperature: {{temp}}</p>
  <p>Description: {{description}}</p>
  <img src="{{icon}}">
</div>
<p *ngIf="error">{{error.message}}</p>
```

INSIDE YOUR STACKBLITZ weather.component.ts

```
getCityData() {
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();
    queryParams = queryParams.append('q', this.cityName);
    queryParams = queryParams.append('appid', this.apiKey);
    this.http.get(this.weatherUrl, {params: queryParams})
      .pipe(debounceTime(500))
      .subscribe(data => {
        //CLEAR HERE OR ACCESS THE LAST OF THE ARRAY
        //this.data[] = []
        // OR
        //this.data[this.data.length-1].....
        //CHECK YOUR DATA 
        //console.log(this.data) so you can see how it is changing over time
        this.data.push(data);
        this.temp = Math.round(this.data[0].main.temp);
        this.description = this.data[0].weather[0]?.description;
        this.icon = this.weatherIconUrl + this.data[0].weather[0]?.icon + '.png';
        this.error = null;
      }, error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
  }
```

Comment: I got service, but I was not sure how should I do it with the queryParams, thx for that. Your solution is working but has one issue, when I type "London", doesn't detect last letter which is pressed, I try with different city names and same issue, but in the template show properly what I type. I put .pipe(debounceTime) before subscribe method in weather component but still same issue, here you can see my request: https://ibb.co/Y8qQLST

Comment: Opps sorry I was a little busy when I wrote the answer. Well I did put the .pipe before the subscribe and it is working.I also added a error variable so you can see the error in the template. Pleas update the weather component ts and html code to see the  changes. I update the code above give it a check it should work now! @KristiyanPetrov

Comment: Also I added error handling when subscribing, now you can get the error message in the template. Hope this helps! @KristiyanPetrov

Comment: I just update my post with the changes, but still same issue, no errors at all, but when I type a city doesnt recognise all keys which I press, but showing in html what did I type correct. Thx

Comment: Hhmmm give me a moment when I arrive home I will recheck again

Comment: Hi I just look at your code, you will never see the error because the p element is inside the div it should be outside. Doing it the way you have it you are saying if !error (if error is null)  show the information and in the p element you are doing the opposite so it should be outside the div... look at my code. I do not what happend that I did not updated the code correctly to display the error so check it again in the part where you subscribe there is the error handling now. Upload a picture to see if we can find something else  besdes the 404 errors.

Comment: sorry my bad I did that late night and I didn’t check what I did, I just fix it now, but still same issue, as last pic which I upload, doesn’t show error.. maybe it’ll be helpful if I upload project to stackblitz so you can see aswell?

Comment: Do that please @Kristiyan Petrov

Comment: I just upload it, I was away sorry about that - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkem24?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: you still do not see the error in the stackblitz? Hmm it is weird because I just opened your code it  is fine and displays the erorr in the html. short video on how I am seeing it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-yu1sXc0JWKPyjHB5fotV1aVgHVxgoef If possible send a video to see what you are getting

Comment: I restart my chrome now it's show error "not found" if name isn't full, so is weird because doesn't have any error when you put full city name, the question is why that's happening and doesn't take new response from api with new data, any suggestions?

Comment: You get an error because this is what the api is sending you when you "type" a name that it can not find .Put this is a normal browser ie: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=0887a6ce526907cc80121d591e5adbdd works but if you send https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Londo&appid=0887a6ce526907cc80121d591e5adbdd it cannot be find in their servers so you get a 404 error.

Comment: another video example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16z0VYHrUL3nFAMhh4lSragWCxhizOLNV

Comment: yes, but my thing is even when I type "London" it seems doesn't make request, because doesn't change the data, I know that why show "Not found", because the city isn't with correct/full name, but the thing is why when you put correct name, doesn't change the data?

Comment: Did you saw the second video @Kristiyan Petrov ?

Comment: Yes I saw it, but did you saw that when you type Miami in the video, doesn't change the data, still show data from London's request

Comment: Sorry I have been busy lately. Ok looking at your code your problem is when you check th array in this.data, you are pushing new data everytime a valid response is send from the server but when you are trying to access that data you are always accessing this.data[0]..... So you will always access the first element in the array. Possible solutions are: 1) Clear the array at the begining before you do push(data) or 2) read from the last element of the list(array). I changed that in your stackblitz and it worked. Anything else let me know :) @KristiyanPetrov

Comment: check edited answer I added the get city function for your specific code... @KristiyanPetrov

Comment: good spot, I didn't know if I say to show [0] from array it'll make that problem, but now I remove it and work properly, thank you so much for the help, it was a bit big conversation, but I'll mark it as answered, thank you again

Comment: No problem we are here to help each other! Take care @Kristiyan Petrov